# Handle stof out of range error

Tags: c++

I am sending some floating value as string from JavaScript to C++ using websocket. Now while converting the value from string to back to float sometimes it gives `out of range` error when the precision is too high like for the input  value in the code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    try {
        string ans = "1.6704779438076223e-52";
        float val = stof(ans);
        cout << val << endl;
    }
    catch (exception &ex) {
        cout << ex.what() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What i want to do is decrease the precision if it is out of range in c++ side so that i can use the value.

Is there any built it function which can do that or do i need to write a separate function to parse the string & check for the precision? Also what things, do i need to check if i need to parse the string manually?

Comment: use stod or stold

Comment: Why aren't you using `double` values, as in JS?

Comment: In js side i am not using any typed variable. Also, i didn't think i will face this problem as the actual value is in range of float but the precision is not. @bob

Comment: Sorry to be nitpicking, but I belived that [JavaScript Numbers are Always 64-bit Floating Point](https://www.w3schools.com/Js/js_numbers.asp) ;), also, the actual value (1.something -52) isn't in [the range of a `float`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985)... In C++, nowadays, is common to use `double`s, unless there are specific reasons.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse it as `double` first with `std::stod` and then assign it to `float`. Then check that `float` for `0`, positive/negative infinity and `NaN`.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, the safest way is to use `std::stod()`, save it to temporary double and then check against `std::numeric_limits<float>::max()` and `std::numeric_limits<float>::min()`.